# Linux Networking Bootup script takes too long

Tags: kernel, boot, wifi, startup, bluetooth

I am working with a fork of a raspberry pi SoC. One of the modification is the use of `AP6210` [WiFi/Bluetooth chip](http://linux-sunxi.org/Cubietruck/AP6210). I am running Debian.

During boot up, the following 3 startup scripts need to run in order:

1. `/init.d/networking` Initializes and powers the chip
2. `/init.d/bluetooth` Initializes the bluetooth HCI socket
3. `/init.d/brcm40183-patch` Applies a [patchram](https://code.google.com/p/broadcom-bluetooth/source/browse/brcm_patchram_plus.c) required for the chip to work.

The problem is that step 1 takes a VERY long time (something like 10s). I think the majority of the process is trying to connect the WLAN.

How can I power the chip, but then run the connecting to WLAN in the background so that the kernel could continue with the rest of the bootup?

Comment: You might want to mention exactly what hardware, and what version of Debian you are using.

Comment: Maybe this could help too: http://www.bootchart.org/